# Is there a javascript combotree control?

Tags: javascript

I need a control which combined of combobox + tree + checkbox  like [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:k3RTBVgTP3UJ:www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combotree.php+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk):

[image]
<sub>(source: [jeasyui.com](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/images/combotree.png))</sub>

This control works but I need to do something with it (collapse all nodes by default) and I cant do it.

Comment: This isn't very clear.  You can't use this control... why?  If you're trying to modify it to "collapse all nodes" and it's not working in some way, show your code and explain the problem.  I'm not sure what you mean by "this site doesn't work with me or its closed" (or why you link to a Google cache instead of the site itself, which seems to work fine).

Comment: @David by "this site doesn't work ..." I mean I can't open the site it self from my country (maybe some restrictions).  and by "collapse all nodes" I mean I want the default status if parent node to be collapsed not expanded because this is my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [dynatree](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/). It should do everything you need, assuming you can run jQuery.

Comment: thanks for your help but I need a tree inside combobox with ability to check multi items

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to combine some of their examples, byt the YUI 2 [treeview widget](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/tv_highlight.html) will do what you want.

Modifying their source is not hard, it's well designed and well written.

See their [treeview example for adding icons](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/customicons.html) to the branches of the tree.